# htaccess file somehow being cached?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I had a .htaccess file doing a very simple rewrite of the page names. This is the contents of the file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule setup setup.php [NC]
```

I now want to stop rewriting setup to setup.php - how do I do this? I've tried removing the line from the file, I've tried deleting the file and restarting apache, and it is *still* rewriting setup to setup.php. How do I make it stop? It seems to be completely ignoring any other .htaccess file I create, and there's nothing being written to the error log. Is it caching the file somewhere? How do I stop it?

I'm using apache2 on ubuntu.

Comment: Also, before you ask, my browser is not caching the page. I checked that already.

Comment: Did you put this rule in your httpd.conf or some conf.d file? Are you sure you're editing the right .htaccess file? Their contents are not cached, they are read on every request.

Comment: it's a file called .htaccess, in the directory /var/www. If I put other files in that directory, they are available at the web root, so I know it's the right place.

Comment: I had the same problem, in my case the browser cached the url redirects

Comment: My browser (firefox) also cached it. Don't know why, but it did !

Comment: @GabrielAnderson Browsers will cache 301 external redirects, in the same way they cache other HTTP responses. However, the question is asking about an internal rewrite, which occurs entirely on the server. It's not the same problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that `MultiViews` is enabled. `MultiViews` automatically adds extensions to any requested URLs, if possible. This has nothing to do with your RewriteRule; it just so happens that you were rewriting `setup` to `setup.php` so `MultiViews` and your rule were doing the same thing.

Add `-MultiViews` to the `Options` directive to disable it.

Comment: Debugging these types of issues can be the worst.  So glad I found your answer early on =) +1

Comment: @nitro2k01 sorry but how exactly to do this? What is options directive? I'm on mamp pro local host, code igniter framework, mac yosemite.

Answer (score 23):

If you are having problems with the htaccess file not updating due to the redirect getting cached in your browser. You can use a webkit browser like Google Chrome or Safari to open a private browsing session or Incognito Window.

Every time you update the htaccess file, you will need to close all incognito windows/tabs and then open a new one. The incognito window will not write to the cache beyond the current session and will not use the existing cache on initial load. It makes a great way to bypass caching issues when testing, and a great way to see if the issue you are having is caused by your browser's cache.

I am not sure, but Firefox and newer versions of IE might have a similar feature.

Comment: In Chrome you can open the dev tools, select the settings icon and enable "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" as well.

Comment: Note that this question is about an _internal rewrite_ that appears to be cached by the _server_. _External redirects_ that are cached by the browser are a different problem.

Comment: Note that this question may or may not be about an *internal rewrite*, because it is hard to test if the browser is caching it. Nothing was ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check to make sure **nginx** is not causing problems for you - I just turned it off, but I'm sure there are ways to set it up properly if you want to use it.  (For me it was set on by default on MediaTemple's newest DV servers).

2) Try adding this to httpd.conf or vhost.conf or some other configuration file further up the food chain from your home directory's htaccess file:

```
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache env=NO_CACHE
Header merge Cache-Control no-store env=NO_STORE
```

Answer (score -2):

The solutions is, to open the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and change this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Into this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Note the AllowOverride directive - this file apparently overrides all other instructions elsewhere.

Comment: That's what you would do if `.htaccess` didn't work at all. That's not Benubird's problem.

Comment: Oh wait, it's your own reply... I still don't see how it is related, though.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Honestly, neither do I- I just did things randomly, then undid them and tried something else, until I found something that worked. Which is why I didn't accept this; I'm still hoping someone can explain it, but htaccess is deep magic.

Comment: Try mine and compare `Options +MultiViews` and `Options -MultiViews` in the `.htaccess`. `AllowOverride All
` is a prerequisite to being able to override the `MultiViews` (or any other) option, though. (Assuming `/var/www/` is your http dir. Otherwise the change you did has no effect.)

Comment: I wonder if the cache didn't just get updated around the time this change was put in place, because it does seem unrelated. I was fighting an htaccess issue recently that was driving me nuts and it was definitely just a cached redirect separate from the cache of the actual page.