# Rewrite URL www.domain.com causing 404 on my page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ok so I've rewrited URL in my website, now for some reason, it is throwing 404 error if I type www.domain.com, if I type domian.com, everything works fine.

```
DirectoryIndex home.php

IndexIgnore *
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/directory/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^home/?$   home.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$   about.php  [NC]

RewriteRule ^404/?$   404.php  [NC]

ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/directory/404
```

Note: I've commented the 1st 2 rewrite rules as even If I change them it doesn't effect after uploading `.htaccess` to server, feels like it's cached.

Additional Info, am using `<base>` tag which is in `embeds.php`

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1') {
    echo '<base href="http://localhost/projects/directory/" />';
} else {
    echo '<base href="http://domain.com/directory/" />';
}
```

Directory Structure

```
Root -
  home.php
  about.php
     -stylesheets
      default.css
     -includes
      embeds.php
  404.php
  .htaccess
```

`embeds.php` is **included** in `home.php`, `about.php` etc, and stylesheets, scripts etc, inshort the head section **along with** `<base>` tag are in `embeds.php`

Comment: What is in [`apache rewrite log`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)? Does the URL get replaced?

Comment: @Vyktor Where I can find a log file? and everything works fine but if I have `www.` in the URL it messes up, and so I used those 2 rules to get rid of the www, but now I am not able to do that too as it is not changing that 2 rules, rest if I edit htaccess and upload it affects but not the first 2 rules

Comment: It depends of settings of your webserver, you may have to reconfigure it (or hopefully `rewritelog` (see url in previous comment) you can add configuration to `.htaccess`).

Comment: And one another thing... do you have `www.domain` configured to the same directory (and IP and so on) to the same as `domain`? Does `www.domain/home.php` work the same as `domain/home.php`?

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to server, and for your second comment, yes, it's the same

Comment: Try adding `RewriteLog "rewrite.log"` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` to your `.htaccess` and create `rewrite.log` and `chmod`-it to `666`.

Comment: @Vyktor Ok wait I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It should work, if it dosn't it comes from your DNS, or Vhost configuration.

Comment: It still redirects to 404 if I type www at the beginning

Comment: +1 and a tick, it works with www as well as without www :D awesome and btw the issue was firefox, and as I already mentioned caching of `.htaccess` this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499541/htaccess-file-somehow-being-cached` of nitro helped, I used chrome and it worked, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

It was also an issue of firefox, which was caching my `.htaccess` file

Here are some useful links which might help other users referring to this question

[Apache - how to disable browser caching while debugging htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743980/apache-how-to-disable-browser-caching-while-debugging-htaccess)

[htaccess file somehow being cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499541/htaccess-file-somehow-being-cached)