# Stop .htaccess from caching

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My old `.htaccess` which redirected my website to `www.domain.com`. However, now I want to change my `.htaccess` to something else (which I did), but my website still gets redirected to `www.domain.com`. If I go into incognito mode the new `.htaccess` works. How to I make it so the old `.htaccess` cache is cleared on my visitors computers.

I had a look at [htaccess file somehow being cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499541/htaccess-file-somehow-being-cached) but I honestly don't understand this because I tried adding `-MultiViews` to my .htaccess.

My new `.htaccess` looks like this. My goal being all URL's get redirected to home page. No matter what URL you type it goes to the homepage.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule .*\.(php|html)$ /index.php [L,R=302]
-MultiViews
```

Comment: Was your previous redirection made by a `301` or a `302` HTTP code?

Comment: @NoahBoegli I honestly can't remember... I think it was a permanent one

Comment: ".htaccess" style files are "distributed configuration files". There is not cache in them, they contain configurations. The client side may cache requests, sure. But that is nothing your configuration can change _afterwards_. The client does not even send a request to your server if it already has a cached result to a previous request.

Comment: @arkascha Does this cache ever expire?

Comment: The cache does not have a duration limit by itself, but it is limited by volume: browsers reserve a certain amount of disk space for this. So the more a browser caches, the sooner entries will get renewed. More important however is that all browsers will obey the http headers sent by the server when objects are delivered. Those headers can name a cache duration, so it is up to what duration your server told the clients to cache the content. Typical values are 30 days for non critical things, for changing content one typically supresses caching.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
Redirect 301  /index.php
```